# Search through a xml using php for a particular value

Tags: php, json, xml

```
<XRF r="9.0.2" c="iD2" g="" u="SG31378-narnapid01" k="969232067" 
d="20170613" t="111536">
<IL k="1">
<I k="86103141,812,333">
<M k="6" b="62409" c="333"/>
<M k="186" b="62409" v="543014"/>
<P k="3,1,1" s="1" td="10" v="9617.5" t="190350" d="20170613" z="1" n="273" 
 b="635"/>
<P k="33,537,1" s="1" td="10" v="-14" t="190350" d="20170613" z="1" n="273" 
b="635"/>
<P k="33,579,1" s="1" td="10" v="-0.145356" t="190350" d="20170613" n="273" 
b="635"/>
<P k="12,0,1" vt="1" s="1" td="10" v="9617.5" t="190350" d="20170613" z="1" 
n="273" b="635"/>
</I>
```

I want to search through a xml file for a specific value like 
   v="9617.5",v="-14",v="-0.145356".I managed to print the fetch the array.But unable to get the values from array.

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: I kept the XML in a variable $myXMLData and used $xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");print_r($xml);

Comment: From there I want the values of v

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath:

```
$xrf = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($xrf->xpath('//*[@v="9617.5"]') as $x) {
  var_dump($x);
}
```

Xpath is an expression language to fetch parts of an DOM (SimpleXML is an abstraction on top of DOM). It is quite powerful, but a little limited if you use it with `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`. For full support you will have to use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.

Comment: $xrf = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/narnolia/public_html/test-xml.php on line 18

Comment: Meaning that the variable `$xml` does not contain an valid XML string. Make sure that it does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
// Loading the XML into a SimpleXmlElement object.
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo '<pre>';
$list = recursiveNodeIteration($xml);
print_r($list);
// Reads the node attributes from the given node.
function getAttributesFromNode(SimpleXMLElement $node)
{
    $nodeAttributes = [];
    foreach ($node->attributes() as $idx => $attribute)
    {
        $nodeAttributes[$idx] = (string)$attribute;
    }
    return $nodeAttributes;
}

// A function to recursively run through the node and its children.
function recursiveNodeIteration(SimpleXMLElement $node)
{
    // Get the node name for reference.
    $nodeName   = $node->getName();
    // Retrieve the attributes
    $attributes = getAttributesFromNode($node);
    $children   = [];
    // Check to see if this node has any children.
    if ($node->count() > 0)
    {
        // If so, run through each child element and retrieve the data.
        foreach ($node->children() as $child)
        {
            $children[] = recursiveNodeIteration($child);
        }
    }
    // Wrap it up in an array and return the dataset.

    return [
        'name'       => $nodeName,
        'attributes' => $attributes,
        'children'   => $children
    ];
}
```

This is your result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => XRF
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [r] => 9.0.2
            [c] => iD2
            [g] => 
            [u] => SG31378-narnapid01
            [k] => 969232067
            [d] => 20170613
            [t] => 111536
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => IL
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [k] => 1
                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => I
                                    [attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [k] => 86103141,812,333
                                        )

                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => M
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 6
                                                            [b] => 62409
                                                            [c] => 333
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => M
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 186
                                                            [b] => 62409
                                                            [v] => 543014
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => P
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 3,1,1
                                                            [s] => 1
                                                            [td] => 10
                                                            [v] => 9617.5
                                                            [t] => 190350
                                                            [d] => 20170613
                                                            [z] => 1
                                                            [n] => 273
                                                            [b] => 635
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => P
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 33,537,1
                                                            [s] => 1
                                                            [td] => 10
                                                            [v] => -14
                                                            [t] => 190350
                                                            [d] => 20170613
                                                            [z] => 1
                                                            [n] => 273
                                                            [b] => 635
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => P
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 33,579,1
                                                            [s] => 1
                                                            [td] => 10
                                                            [v] => -0.145356
                                                            [t] => 190350
                                                            [d] => 20170613
                                                            [n] => 273
                                                            [b] => 635
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => P
                                                    [attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [k] => 12,0,1
                                                            [vt] => 1
                                                            [s] => 1
                                                            [td] => 10
                                                            [v] => 9617.5
                                                            [t] => 190350
                                                            [d] => 20170613
                                                            [z] => 1
                                                            [n] => 273
                                                            [b] => 635
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I am getting this error.Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/narnolia/public_html/test-xml.php on line 19.The error is on this line.$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);